# Universal link doesn't open the app on iOS

Tags: ios, deeplink

I have an app with MagicLink authentication implemented using universal links. The app and the server are configured to handle universal links following Apple’s documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html).

The link successfully launches the app from Apple Mail + Safari. However when I try to open it from GoogleMail + Chrome, it redirect to the AppStore.

It is important to notice that the app isn’t on the AppStore yet and I’m trying to sort out the issue before publishing it.

I can reproduce the issue on the iPhone 6s with iOS 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue with a number of apps. Universal Links do not work in many situations, with the Gmail app being one of them. See a more detailed list [here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/support/ios/#appsbrowsers-that-support-universal-links).

To work around this limitation, your Universal Link URL needs to lead to a page with a button/link on it the user can activate. At [Branch.io](https://branch/io), we offer a [Deepviews](https://dev.branch.io/features/deepviews/overview/) feature for this purpose. You'll need to build something similar.

Comment: Hi Alex, I looked at the 'Deepviews' and the documentation on your website says '...visitor opens one of your Branch links and does not have your app installed, you can show them a Deepview... .'

Comment: How will Deepview help with the case if the app IS already installed, but universal link fails to open it?

Comment: @ValentinBalaschenko if a Universal Link from Branch is opened and the app is installed but doesn't launch for some reason (e.g., opening within Facebook), then the Deepview will load. Since the Deepview has a button that either launches the app (if installed) _or_ redirects to the App Store (if not installed), you basically get a free 'second chance' with that user. Without a Deepview (or similar option), your user gets the App Store immediately as you are observing